# particles with circular motion

Tags: after-effects, motion-graphics

I'm traying to create this graphic for my on going project, I tried to guess some techniques but wasn't successful, I was messing around with physics and sphere field in Trapcode Particular but it wasn't quiet right, if anybody would like to share how it might have been achieved, I'd be much appreciated, thanks!

[image: particle effect]